# how to setup jsoncpp for use in visual c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, jsoncpp

I want to use `jsoncpp` in visual studio. Can someone guide me the steps involved.
I am trying call a rest-service by serializing class object to json

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create amalgamated sources (a single `.cpp` file and two `.h` files) in your project, and compile and build as you would any other source file. This ensures consistency of compilation flags and ABI compatibility, issues which arise when building shared or static libraries.

For more info check: [jsoncpp generating-amalgamated-source-and-header](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/wiki/Amalgamated#generating-amalgamated-source-and-header)

Comment: I am new to c++. i tried to use from nuget, but when i build the project it is not compiling giving linker errors. can you please let me know the steps to create amalgamated source in my project.

Comment: Maybe start at a simple walkthrough? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384842.aspx

Comment: I am able to do basic programming in cpp, but i have to serialize a class and do a post request with json data in cpp. but i am stuck setting up with jsoncpp. so need help